# problem in copying find results in another directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to execute this command to copy the latest file that exist in the courant directory to another one .

```
find . -mtime -1 -exec cp -r {} /media/96DB-120D/bck \;
```

but after copying the recent files , I find the other content of the folder that does not respond to the condition `-mtime -1` .

If any one had an idea about how to fix it to just copy the result of find command and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command probably includes the directory and then `cp` copies all the files in the directory.  Add `-type f` to only have `find` report actual files.

Comment: The purpose of the `-r` option is murky if you don't want to include directories, though. Are you actually hoping to recreate the source directory structure on the target? Maybe try `rsync` instead of `cp` which helpfully avoids the whole `find` conundrum at the same time, too.

Comment: i do not have much space rsync copy all the content of the current directory to the target directory for that i use find to limit the number of file tht i want to copy

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `rsync` is better at copying just the new files with the directory structure intact if that's what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to keep the structure of my source folder into the destination folder for that i use cp -r

Comment: the goal is to have only in the target folder , the file and the folder that had been created yesterday

Comment: if there is an option in rsync to just limit the transfer of the files that had been created for example yesterday it will be good solution

Comment: "Preserve directory structure" means `path/to/file.jpg` gets copied to `destination/path/to/file.jpg` instead of `destination/file.jpg`. You have still not made clear if this is what you are hoping to accomplish. If it is, `cp -r` does not do that. Once you have properly explained what you wish, we can talk about how to get it done.

Comment: i hope to accomplish what you just write now but cp -r does not do that but it copy all files that exists in the source directory without considering the condition -mtime -1

Comment: I have explained exactly why that happens in this answer. The directory was changed less than a day ago if it contains any files which are less than a day old, and so `find` prints the directory name, and so you tell `cp` to copy the whole directory.

Comment: so solution is: **find . -mtime -1 -type f -exec cp -pr {} /media/96DB-120D/bck \;**

Comment: to copy only files that had been created today with conservation of structure under the destination folder

Comment: what is the difference between them ?

Comment: I was reading the BSD manual page which simply recommends avoiding `-r` without detailing its semantics. On GNU (and thus Linux), apparently no difference; they are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Try the -p option of `cp` command which will preserve the timestamp of the copied file:

```
find . -mtime -1 -exec cp -pr {} /media/96DB-120D/bck \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution :

```
find . -mtime -1 -type f -exec cp --parents {} /media/960DB-120D/db \;
```